# C# White Framework Automation: How to check if a page was opened

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation, automated-tests, white-framework

I have to write white/c# code to check if a confirmation page was opened after clicking a button. If it didn't open it means there was some sort of problem and the test needs to fail.
Afterwards i need to use that page in order to push another button on it.

Anyone know how to do that using white/c# syntax ?

Thanks in advance

LE: this is what i wrote

```
public virtual void gotoSave(String Option)
{
    btnSave.Click();
    if (Option == "Save")
    {
         btnSave.Click();
    }
}
```

and in the Test in am writing

```
depositPage.gotoSave();
```

where depositPage is the Father page

When clicking on save I need to assert if a Confirmation Page has been opened, if not the test has to fail.

I know how to get pages using `GetPage<>()` directive but I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Can you post the code you have written that didn't work for you?

Comment: @Mharlin posted the code above. I am really a White beginner and don't know all it's in's and outs